# VSCode: focus on file after clicking on it it in file explorer

Tags: visual-studio-code

I swear something has changed with VS code. You used to be able to click on a file in the file explorer, and it would automatically focus on the body of the file, *so you can start typing immediately*. Now, (1.36.1), when you click on a file in the file explorer, it stays focused on the file explorer, so if you start typing after clicking, it will start a search inside the explorer instead of the editor. This is extremely user hostile and I *really* want it disabled, it's totally throwing off my flow. How can I disable this?

Comment: Are you single-clicking or double?  Double always moves focus for me.

Comment: single clicking, which used to always work for me.

Comment: Is there any traction on this? This is a serious annoyance.